# Difference in memory usage between readAsText and readAsArrayBuffer methods

Tags: javascript

I plant to upload local file by using input-type=file HTML element.

Before I upload it to server...
I have to check there are essential column title in CSV file.

So I try to do this

```js
const validFileRow = (event) => {
    const [file] = event.target.files;
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    reader.onload = (evtReader) => {
      const data = evtReader.target.result;
      const ui8a = new Uint8Array(data);
      const byteLength = data.byteLength;
      let rowString = '';

      for (let i = 0; i < byteLength; i++) {
        let char = String.fromCharCode(ui8a[i]);
        if (char.match(/[^\r\n]+/g) !== null) {
          rowString += char;
        } else {
          break;
        }
      }
    };
  };
```

But, I have question.

1. In terms of saving memory, is there any difference between readAsArrayBuffer and readAsText?
2. Like I did, If I load the entire file using uint8Array method (omitted offset, length ), it will eventually save the entire file in memory, so doesn't it save memory?

Answer (score 0):

The `readAsText` method loads the *full file into memory* before processing it. This can be an issue when the file size becomes large and exceeds resource limitations, particularly when dealing within a browser environment. A few KB is fine, but as the file grows larger, performance issues and crashes are only a matter of time.

The `readAsArrayBuffer` method stores the data provided in binary array in RAM. This capability allows you to work with defined sections of the data at a time, without loading the full file into memory and crashing the browser or computer. A workflow using the `splice` method is provided [here](https://joji.me/en-us/blog/processing-huge-files-using-filereader-readasarraybuffer-in-web-browser/) for larger files where memory saving is a concern.

**If I load the entire file using uint8Array method (omitted offset, length ), it will eventually save the entire file in memory, so doesn't it save memory?**
Correct. If you load the entire file using `uint8Array8`, it will try to save the entire file in working memory. However, this is not necessary as the file's data can be broken into discrete chunks of data following the method linked to above.